Has there been any pressure for investigating the Omar Al-Bayoumi angle of the 9/11 attacks?
Over the past few years, some documents have been declassified in the US regarding a person called Omar Al-Bayoumi. Apparently:

An FBI report declassified in September 2021 lays out evidence that
al-Bayoumi ... provided significant support
to 9/11 hijackers Nawaf al-Hazmi and Khalid al-Mihdhar ... and communicated with a key logistics facilitator
for Osama bin Laden, each time immediately following significant
logistics support to Hazmi and Mihdhar.

and:

In March 2022, the FBI declassified a... report [that] found that "there is a 50/50 chance
[al-Bayoumi] had advanced knowledge the 9/11 attacks were to occur"
from the two Islamists he befriended that were involved in plotting
9/11.

and finally, the Guardian reported in 2020 that:

... al-Bayoumi began receiving
... monthly payment... from... the
wife of Bandar bin Sultan, the Saudi ambassador to the U.S.

So, disclosures to the public in 2020, 2021 and 2022 - fairly recent; and their combination creates a suspicion of close involvement of the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia in the hijackings and crashes into the WTC towers (and the Pentagon?). I realize that those three years coincided with the Covid pandemic, and this may not have been an absolutely pressing immediate concern, but:

Has there been any public pressure to investigate this "angle" of the possible involvement of the KSA government in the September 11th, 2001 hijackings?
If there has been -  what made it fizzle out?


Per ProPublica there is clearly pressure from the families who are sueing in court, but it looks like it's too soon to say where this will wind up.

@BrianZ: Weird how nearly a quarter-century after the fact it's still too soon for investigations of this historical event.

@einpoklum - Yeah...I think it's pretty clear that Brian is saying that it looks like it is too soon to know the results of the lawsuit, which has not yet had a verdict, not that it is too soon for any investigations of the September 11 attacks, of which there have been quite a few.

@Obie2.0: Sure, but - what about the public pressure to have this investigated? I don't follow US mass media, but - has there been discussion of these findings? has it led to any sessions in the federal congress, or the NY state institutions?


Question:
Has there been any pressure for investigating the Omar Al-Bayoumi angle of the 9/11 attacks?

Well you yourself said there were reports released in 2020, 2021, and 2022.  So clearly there have been investigations.  Here is the thing though, even if Al-Boyoumi was a Saudi agent, which the Saudi's deny, it is more likely he would be watching the 9/11 terrorists because Al Quada was outlawed in Saudi Arabia as a threat to the Kingdom years prior to 9/11.  Saudi intelligence had every reason to keep track of them and want to know what they were up too for their own security interests.  It's a huge leap to move from Saudi was watching them, too Saudi Arabia was conspiring with them to kill 2000 U.S. citizens.  According to the reports they don't even know whether Al-Boyoumi was a Saudi agent, they just suspect it.
The regime in power in Saudi Arabia was very close to the West.  They had keep oil prices low for two decades and made a ton of money in the process of doing so.  It doesn't make any sense they would have fore knowledge of 911 and keep it to themselves.   Saudi was a key ally to the west.

Well, we're talking about an investigation, not an ICC indictment of Saudi officials. And - funding the 9/11 hijackers through him is a couple of steps bridging the "huge leap", after all.

@einpoklem, Where did "ICC indictment" come from?  and Al Quada didn't need Saudi Royal money, the bin laudin's owned the largest engineering firm in Saudi,  so he had plenty of money to fund his operations.  911 cost what less than $100k.  The cost of 15 coach one way airline tickets.

All true, but keep in mind that Saudi activities wrt both regular Muslim concerns, as well as extremist Islamist support, ranged from the official support for building mosques to sizable donations made by wealthy Saudis to extremists.  So, while it most likely is true the government had nothing to do with 9/11, that doesn't mean some fairly significant Saudis didn't support some "bad guys" without looking too closely as to what they were up to.  Still worth looking into for the US, if substantiated.  Unless of course there are "state reasons" for aiming for the underside of the nearest carpet.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Correct but the hypothesis in this case was that Omar Al-Bayoumi worked for Saudi intelligence not for some rogue Saudi element which certainly exist.
